# Not call data property from Bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-directives

My problem: I can't target data element(show: false), and use Vue directive v-show: to hide element what I want.

[image]

This "show" property changing when toggle menu button is a click.
And in console possible call this "show" property writing $vm0.show
But how I can target this property in v-show: directive?

[Follow this link for code hosted on Github](https://github.com/dmitri-jurovski/soa-helsinki)

Comment: I suggest: put your minimal code here. You will have then more opportunities to get an answer.

Comment: Please read: **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**